# Make API call when mat-table row is expanded

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I want to make an API call when the user selects a row to show more details of that particular record in the expansion. I am referring to https://stackblitz.com/angular/ngrkjbrexbj?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you made an attempt to try and solve this? This can be easily done by just calling a function on the `click` event and then calling your API within this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `(click)` listener that sets `expandedElement` to current's row element. Hook into this event.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-35wzca

you will see `console.log` message in the console when row is expanding.

Comment: How do I display the data which I got from the API?

Comment: Update `exandedPanel` content acordingly.

Comment: @fvales Consider upvote and accepting answer for future readers.